# Need help trying to make FullCalendar persistant through a postback

Tags: javascript, webforms, fullcalendar

So I have a calendar displayed on one of my webform pages. Works great and serves purpose for end users. However to add/edit events I create a postback that resets the view to its default. Only an issue for the administrator but he will often will add entries a year or more in advance making this a nuisance.

To try and solve this I added a hidden textbox to store the start date of the calendar view.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSaveTheDate" style="display:none;" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then in each event I update the date to the current view. You will never get a postback unless you have triggered an event first)

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        document.getElementById('<%=txtSaveTheDate.ClientID%>').value = view.start.format();
        ...
},
```

I then use the defaultDate attribute to use this date to show the last shown date range in the calendar.

```
defaultDate: moment(SaveTheDate),
```

This works 80%.
When I click on the calendar to create an event the proper date moves into the textbox.
However, once the page postback The calendar return to one month before where it should. This happens if you are in the present, past or future. The only time it goes to the proper date is Jan 2023, for whatever reason that month works. The only clue is that the display starts on the 1st of the month unlike most.

Any Tips would be appreciated including alternate techniques.

Full procedure for reference.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        SaveTheDate = document.getElementById('<%=txtSaveTheDate.ClientID%>').value;
        if (SaveTheDate == '') {
            SaveTheDate = new Date();
        };            
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: "{}",
            url: "TrainingCalendar.aspx/GetEvents",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('div[id*=fullcal]').fullCalendar({
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month'
                    },
                    defaultDate: moment(SaveTheDate), 
                    displayEventTime: false,                        
                    events: $.map(data.d, function (item, i) {
                        var event = new Object();
                        event.id = item.EventID
                        event.start = new Date(item.StartDate);
                        event.end = new Date(item.EndDate);
                        event.title = item.EventName;
                        event.backgroundColor = item.Color;
                        event.textColor = item.TextColor;
                        return event;
                    }),                        
                    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                        //Let's make sure they have permissions to edit the page
                        if (document.getElementById('<%=btnNotes.ClientID%>')) {
                            document.getElementById('<%=txtSaveTheDate.ClientID%>').value = view.start.format();
                            document.getElementById('<%=txtEventId.ClientID%>').value = calEvent.id;
                            document.getElementById('<%=txtEventName.ClientID%>').value = calEvent.title;
                            var date = new Date(calEvent.start);
                            document.getElementById('<%=txtDate.ClientID%>').value = ((date.getMonth() > 8) ? (date.getMonth() + 1) : ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1))) + '/' + ((date.getDate() > 9) ? date.getDate() : ('0' + date.getDate())) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
                            $('#EventModal').modal('show');
                        }
                    },
                    dayClick: function (dt, jsEvent, view) {
                        //Let's make sure they have permissions to edit the page
                        if (document.getElementById('<%=btnNotes.ClientID%>')) {
                            document.getElementById('<%=txtSaveTheDate.ClientID%>').value = view.start.format();
                            document.getElementById('<%=ddlNewEventName.ClientID%>').value = '0';
                            document.getElementById('<%=txtNewEventName.ClientID%>').value = '';
                            document.getElementById('<%=txtNewDate.ClientID%>').value = dt.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
                            $('#NewEventModal').modal('show');
                        }
                    }
                });
                $("div[id=loading]").hide();
                $("div[id=fullcal]").show();
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                debugger;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: localStorage or sessionStorage is the answer

Comment: @mplungjan - local storage I get, but how does this help the if its going to store the value I am using in the textbox it should have the same strange behavior.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object - look at the timezone. If it is a fullday, then remove the time part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have discovered by hardcoding some values that "defaultDate" needs to see the first day of the month's view, not the first day displayed in the view.

This will vary based on the version you are on but...

```
 document.getElementById('<%=txtSaveTheDate.ClientID%>').value = view.start.format();
```

Returns the first date on the calendar

Changing from start to intervalStart gets you the first day of the month.

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtSaveTheDate.ClientID%>').value = view.intervalStart.format();
```

The syntax is different based on the version, intervalStart is compatible for version 3.

Here are the view objects available, you can select your version to change the content.
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/view-object